# Logging MySQL query on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I need to log SQL to a file so i can check later which SQL run.

so i opened `opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` and add these lines

```
log_slow_queries  
log_queries_not_using_indexes =1  
long_query_time = 1  
slow_query_log = 1  
slow_query_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"
```

but it did not logged the queries it even did not created the query.log file, so i created an empty file with the name, but still it's not working.

`Edit`

```
[mysqld]
log_slow_queries
log_queries_not_using_indexes =1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
general_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /opt/lampp/logs/query.log
general_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"
```

Comment: yup, i restarted & reloaded both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will only log slow queries. You need the general log if you want to see all queries.

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"
```

Note that you'll need to restart the server for this to take effect. Also, you should only use this type of logging during testing as it does cause slowdown.

As other users mentioned, this could be a permissions issue. First, check what user MySQL is running as via `ps -u -p $(pgrep mysql)`. The username will be displayed on the first column under `USER`. In your case, it seems the user is `nobody`. You can view the default group of a user via `groups nobody`. This should print something like `nobody : nogroup`.

To fix the permissions on the file, just run `chown nobody:nogroup /opt/lampp/logs/query.log`.

Comment: Check the output of `show variables like 'general_log%';` to confirm that MySQL has applied your settings.

Comment: how to get the mysql console ?

Comment: Typing `mysql -hHOST_NAME -uUSER_NAME -DDATABASE_NAME -p` at the command line will connect you.

Comment: if i type in terminal it shows not installed :( but i'm working with MySQL and have developed site in LAMPP

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

Comment: i've copied my.cnf file, review it

Comment: I suspect you can't have the general log and the slow query log go to the same file.

Comment: i turned off the SLOW_QUERY_LOG still the problem exist. `+1 for so much effort :)`

Comment: Try `ps u -p \`pgrep mysql\`` to confirm that MySQL is in fact running as the user `mysql`.

Comment: USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND  
root      1496  0.0  0.0   1912   448 ?        S    18:12   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/la  
nobody    1899  0.1  6.2 190264 31712 ?        Sl   18:12   0:02 /opt/lampp/sbin

Comment: Ah, well then. It appears that `mysql` is running as user `nobody` rather than `mysql`. Try `chown nobody:nobody /opt/lampp/logs/query.log`, followed by a restart of MySQL.

Comment: chown: invalid group: `nobody:nobody'

Comment: Ah, right. I believe `nobody` is actually a member of the group `nogroup`. You can confirm via `groups nobody`. This should output `nobody : nogroup`. Try `chown nobody:nogroup /opt/lampp/logs/query.log`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked :) I'll request you to put this steps in your answer so other people can find it easily, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to give the correct permission  :

```
chown mysql:mysql filename
```

also when i last did it , i had to restart the mysql service :

```
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: did you restart mysql ?  service mysqld restart

Comment: yup i restarted but still no result !

Comment: are you sure the query is slow to be logged ?

Comment: can u edit your question and past the content of your  my.cnf file

Comment: i've copied my.cnf file, review it

Comment: not sure if u have a syntax error in ur cnf file try adding a path to log-slow-queries=/var/log/log-slow-queries.log also check the error log when u restart the mysqld service

Comment: it's still a 0 byte file, after restarting MYSQL and running some SQL

Comment: maybe this will help u http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: that did not helped :( `+1 for so much effort :)`

Answer (score 2):

```
log_slow_queries
```

is deprecated

It now has to look like that:

```
slow_query_log
log_queries_not_using_indexes =1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
general_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The process probably doesn't have permission to write to that directory. Make sure MySQL has permission to write there, or try logging somewhere less restricted.

Comment: i'm new to linux, please guide to do so

Answer (score 1):

This will only log slow queries. You need the general log if you want to see all queries.

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"
```

Note that you'll need to restart the server for this to take effect. Also, you should only use this type of logging during testing as it does cause slowdown.

Also Note that mysql needs permissions over folder too, in my case, I changed:
`general_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"`
for
`general_log_file = "/var/log/mysql/query.log"`
But I have mysql installed from software center, without lampp, when I execute ls -l over /var/log/, it shows
`drwx------ 8 mysql         mysql         4096 sep 25 23:22 mysql`

---

PD:I change the my.cn file and restart mysql, without create the query.log file in the specified path, mysql automatically create it